# Using UL Vs Divs to create a tabular layout

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to create tabular layout?

1. Using UI/LI and make Li display:inline?
2. Using divs with float and position property

Answer (score 2):

If you want to design a layout **DO NOT USE TABLES**, if you want it for a tabular data, **ONLY USE TABLES**

So in short if you want to create a layout like a side bar, with a content area, header and footer you should use `<div>` and new HTML5 tags if you prefer to, like `<header>, <footer>, <nav>, <section> <article>` etc...If you need to generate tabular data like reports, results etc, than just use tables *(It's meant for that)*...

About the `<ul>` - Just use it for making menu(navigation) or an unordered list

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually my layout looks like table. Example: picture on the left, title of the picture, author name, price, a icon to select the row. We can have as many we want. Do you suggest to table for this kind of layout. Why not UL?

Comment: `<ul>` is simply meant for list or navigation purposes, these types of data is well suited with div's(If your CSS is strong), if you are weak with positioning and floats, I would first suggest you to learn that else you've `table` as an option, if you want, just show me a layout blueprint and I'll make a demo for you

Comment: Sure. I will use Div. I always use DIV's, this time i thought of trying with <ul>.

Comment: @Ohm nah you are kinda complicating the things using lists, `div` is the always preferred way to go for